# Is it possible to embed a Google Map in a Github pages site?

Tags: google-maps, iframe, github-pages

Does anyone know if it's possible to embed a Google Map using `iframe` into a Github pages page built using the automatic page generator?

For example, I would like to embed something like this:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m16!1m12!1m3!1d100921.8397227734!2d-122.50711698562192!3d37.77111185957552!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!2m1!1sGithub!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1464784986282" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

When I try to embed the above, however, the `iframe` element appears to be stripped from the final HTML so that no map is shown.

I looked around a bit and couldn't find much information on embedding maps, or in general, using iframe elements in Github pages.

People appear to have luck [embedding Youtube videos](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/346) within an iframe, but the same tweak does not help with the maps.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will not be allowed to insert iframe from the page generator.

You have to edit your page from, for example, https://github.com/username/repositoryname/blob/gh-pages/index.html, by clicking on edit button (see picture) and insert your iframe code.

[image]

Comment: Thanks David! Indeed that is what I ultimately ended up doing. Forgot to post the solution afterwards though. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: The "See example code here and result here" links now result in 404's

Comment: @mike-gifford thank you for noticing. I've reestablished links.